# Javascript Number to Roman Conversion

Tags: javascript

I was looking to convert from Number to Roman (X, IV etc).

Someone proposed this solution, I'm going through the solution but I wasn't able to understand even though I debugged it.

Can someone explain what's going on? I'm just trying to learn some JS.

```js
function convertToRoman(num) {

  var roman =  {"M" :1000, "CM":900, "D":500, "CD":400, "C":100, "XC":90, "L":50, "XL":40, "X":10, "IX":9, "V":5, "IV":4, "I":1};
    str = "";

  for (var i in roman ) {
    var q = Math.floor(num / roman[i]); //Why?
    num -= q * roman[i]; //Why?
    str += i.repeat(q); //Why?
  }

  return str;

}
```

Comment: All those statements you commented are pretty simple. Could you explain what you find confusing about them, so we can know what needs to be explained?

Comment: The code uses assumed knowledge of how to convert Arabic digits  into  Roman numerals. It uses at most one lesser value prefix letter to indicate  subtraction from a following larger value letter. It produces MCMXC  for 1990 and never XMM. **This is not a javascript question.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Description

Code described in comments below.

```js
// this is a function declaration
// with a parameter called num
function convertToRoman(num) {
  // this is an object, being used as a lookup
  var roman =  {"M" :1000, "CM":900, "D":500, "CD":400, "C":100, "XC":90, "L":50, "XL":40, "X":10, "IX":9, "V":5, "IV":4, "I":1};
  console.log('num = ' + num);
  
  // this is a variable of type string
  str = "";

  // for loop to go over each item in roman
  for (var i in roman ) {
    console.log('i = ' + i);
    // calculates the Math Floor of the number passed in divided by the roman value
    // this will do the number passed divided by 1000 first
    // Example: convertToRoman(1201)
    // Math.floor(1201 / 1000) = 1
    var q = Math.floor(num / roman[i]); //Why?
    console.log('q = ' + q);
    // remove the value of q multiplied by roman[i]
    // Example: convertToRoman(1201)
    // q = 1
    // num = num - 1 * 1000;
    // this makes it so that num is less the roman symbol we just found
    num -= q * roman[i]; //Why?
    console.log('num = ' + num);
    // this is to make the roman number string
    // Example: num = 1201
    // i = 1000
    // q = 1
    // str = str + "M";
    // or
    // num = 3102
    // i = 1000
    // q = 3
    // str = str + "M" [repeated 3 times]
    // str = 'MMM' at the end of this
    str += i.repeat(q); //Why?
    console.log('str = ' + str);
  }

  // return the string
  return str;
}

console.log(convertToRoman(1201));
```

Answer (score 0):

The var roman is an associative array with key being a string and value the decimal system value.

It's ordered descending in value.

The loop iterates the array calculating the max times each value at index is contained within the given number, and subtracting it from the number so that the new iteration can continue calculating the "rest"